# Composing Drawables - Cannot get Scale Drawable to render correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable

I'm trying to achieve a highlight-able, circular button with a scaled image layered on top, however the image doesn't render at all when wrapped in `<scale>` tag.

Here is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <!-- Highlighted Button (when pressed) -->

  <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <layer-list>
      <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
          <solid android:color="#FFFFE000" />
          <stroke android:color="#FF000000" android:width="2dp" />
          <size android:width="50dp" android:height="50dp" />
        </shape>
      </item>

      <!-- This will render, but I want this image scaled smaller -->
      <!--item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checkmark_holo_light"/-->

      <item>
        <scale android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checkmark_holo_light"
               android:scaleWidth="75%" android:scaleHeight="75%"
               android:scaleGravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>
      </item>
    </layer-list>
  </item>

  <!-- Un-Highlighted Button (not pressed) -->

  <item>
    <layer-list>
      <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
          <solid android:color="#FFEAEAEA" />
          <stroke android:color="#FF000000" android:width="2dp" />
          <size android:width="50dp" android:height="50dp" />
        </shape>
      </item>

      <!-- This will render, but I want this image scaled smaller -->
      <!--item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checkmark_holo_light"/-->

      <item>
        <scale android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checkmark_holo_light"
               android:scaleWidth="75%" android:scaleHeight="75%"
               android:scaleGravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>
      </item>
    </layer-list>
  </item>

</selector>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm targeting 4.0.3 (I know, its old, but it's not my choice). Thank you.